# Getting empty dataframe that is actually being filled when using multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have a class that aims to populate a queue, process the queue and add the results of the queue into a dataframe.

The code runs fine and the dataframe is actually being filled in the `_populate_df` function, but when I try to access the resulting dataframe, I get an empty dataframe. Why? How can I get the dataframe filled?

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
     
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager    
    
class Ensambler():
    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = Manager()
        self.queue = self.manager.Queue(maxsize=20)
        self.df_queue = self.manager.Queue(maxsize=20)
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.lock = self.manager.Lock()
            
    def _populate_queue(self):
        while True:
            try:
                c = np.random.randint(0,10)
                self.queue.put(c)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break

    def _populate_df(self,df):
        df['queue_items'] = None
        while True:
            try:
                if not self.df_queue.empty():
                    item = self.df_queue.get()
                    df.loc[df.shape[0],'queue_items'] = item
                print(df.shape)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break
                
    def _process_queue(self,idx):
        while True:
            try:
                self.lock.acquire()
                item = self.queue.get()
                # print(idx,item)
                self.df_queue.put(item)
                self.lock.release()
                sleep(0.1)
                
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break
        
    
    def run(self,n_workers):
        try:
            populate = Process(target=self._populate_queue)
            populate_df = Process(target=self._populate_df,args=(self.df,))
            jobs = [populate,populate_df]
            for _ in range(n_workers):
                
                p = Process(target = self._process_queue, args=(_,))
                jobs.append(p)
            for job in jobs:
                job.start()

            for idx,job in enumerate(jobs):
                
                job.join()
                if not job.is_alive():
                    
                    job.close()
                else:
                    
                    job.terminate()

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            for idx,job in enumerate(jobs):
                
                job.join()
                if not job.is_alive():
                    
                    job.close()
                else:
                    
                    job.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    ens = Ensambler()
    
    ens.run(16)
    print(ens.df)
```

Comment: That dataframe is not in shared memory.  Each process has its own copy.  You need to look at some other scheme to return data from the subprocesses back to the parent.  Something like a `multiprocessing.Queue`, maybe.

Comment: Your code doesn't work, `Ensambler` does not take any argument and you create an instance with 2 arguments. @TimRoberts, `Manager` allows processes to share data with some limitations (no nested data structure). You can refer to [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Comment: @Corralien fixed the arguments part.

Comment: @xerac. And what about `_shuffle` attribute? Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: @Corralien sorry, I corrected the code and changed `_shuffle` to `_process_queue`. I changed the function's name in order to ask the question, so their names can be more "logical". Like "here is where I populate the queue, here where I process the queue and here where I wish to fill the dataframe".